# Is setting ulimit in neo4j-service an acceptable method

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I have prepended to /etc/inti.d/neo4j-service

```
ulimit -n 40000
```

Does this method of increasing the ulimit serve neo4j's needs?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing there [is recommended in the linux performance guide](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/linux-performance-guide.html#_setting_the_number_of_open_files).   40,000 is considered a healthy limit that ought to work in most cases.

Indexes eat up open files, so do network connections.  40,000 ought to be OK for most people, most of the time, but it depends on how many simultaneous connections you expect, and how aggressive your indexing is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it does indeed 'work' neo4j does not warm me any longer. I'm curious specifically with neo4j if setting it this way has a wide enough scope for neo4j's needs since other answers regarding neo4j ulimit do not have this solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "wide enough scope for neo4j's needs"?  If you configure the server, what else do you have that's wider than that scope that would need to open files?

Comment: I'm thinking of a secondary neo4j related process that runs outside of the neo4j service that might need that value. Since neo4j performance guide recommends using the limits.conf/pam.d method.